# Printing a value from a randint

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import os
import random

path = os.listdir(r"file path here")
list = [os.listdir(r"life path here")]


print(len(path))

for i in range(len(path)):
    full_path = (r"file path here" + path[i])
    print(full_path)
print_random_items = random.randint(0, len(path[i]))
print(print_random_items)
```

So Hi I would like to know how I can print the name of the file associated with the value return to print(print_random_items)

ex: If the value is 15 I would like to print the 15th files name

First time asking a question here sorry if the format is wrong.

Comment: Just a hint: There is no inherent order in filenames. See e.g. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_listdir.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't bother with the random numbers. Just use `random.choice`:

```
random.choice(paths)
```

For example:

```
>>> import random
>>> paths = os.listdir('./exampledir')
>>> paths
['a.txt', 'b.txt', 'c.txt', 'd.txt', 'e.txt', 'f.txt']
>>> random.choice(paths)
'e.txt'
>>> random.choice(paths)
'c.txt'
```

**Note:**  I see in your code that you are not familiar with python style iteration.

This

```
for i in range(len(path)):
    full_path = (r"file path here" + path[i])
    print(full_path)
```

is better written as

```
for partial_path in path:
    full_path = r"file path here" + partial_path
    print(full_path)
```

So rather than using `range(len(path))` to get an index you can just iterate over `path` directly.